# Gradle + Embedded Jetty

Tags: spring, hibernate, gradle, jetty

I have modified an existing Jetty project and after I builded, I got 404. Maybe I need to modify other files which I do not know.
I am using gradle to build. Here is the build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile  'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.6.Final'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.14'
}
test {
    exclude '**/*IntegrationTest*'
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    include '**/*IntegrationTest*'
    doFirst {
        jettyRun.contextPath = '/';
        jettyRun.httpPort = 8080    // Port for test
        jettyRun.daemon = true
        jettyRun.execute()
    }
    doLast {
        jettyStop.stopPort = 8091   // Port for stop signal
        jettyStop.stopKey = 'stopKey'
        jettyStop.execute()
    }
}


// Embeded Jetty for testing
jettyRun{
    contextPath = "spring4"
    httpPort = 8080
}

jettyRunWar{
    contextPath = "spring4"
    httpPort = 8080
}


//For Eclipse IDE only
eclipse {

  wtp {
    component {

      //define context path, default to project folder name
      contextPath = 'spring4'

    }

  }
}
```

Here the other class:

```
package com.hello.webapp;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import com.hello.service.SignUpService;

@Path("/signUp")
public class SignUpWebapp {
    private static SignUpService signUpService = new SignUpService();

    @GET()
    public String hello() {
        return signUpService.sayHello();
    }
}
```

here the simple service:

```
package com.hello.service;

public class SignUpService {

    public String sayHello() {
        return "signUp";
    }

}
```

this is another the integration test class

```
package com.hello.webapp;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SignUpIntegrationTest {
    private static String SIGNUP = "http://localhost:8080/signUp";

    @Test
    public void testHello() throws Exception {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(SIGNUP);
        String response = webTarget.request().get(String.class);

        assertThat(response, is("signUp"));
    }
}
```

So, when I run `gradle integrationTest` I get an error saying that Jetty is already running. And when I try to visit `localhost/signUp` I get a 404.

Comment: The `jetty` plugin is outdated and will likely be removed. You should be using [gretty](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty)

Comment: Calling the `execute()` method on any task is highly discouraged. You should define task execution order with `dependsOn` and `finalizedBy`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use gretty instead:

```
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'
....
classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:1.4.0'
...
gretty {
    port = 8083
    contextPath = '/'
    servletContainer = 'jetty9'
    jvmArgs = [
            '-Xms700m',
            '-Xmx2048m'
            ]
    loggingLevel='INFO'
    debugPort = 5005      // default
    debugSuspend = true   // default

    httpsEnabled = true
    httpsPort = 8443
    sslKeyStorePath = 'some.jks'
    sslKeyStorePassword = 'somepwd'
}
```

and then gradle appStart

Let me know if that helps.